# How to create new Activity/fragment in kotlin folder

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I decided to change the java folder in my project.
I renamed app->src->main->java folder to app->src->main->kotlin

[image: Kotlin folder]

Then I correct the path in the Gradle by below code

```
    sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

problem: When I want to create new activity or fragment by the wizard, new classes are created on the java folder even if I do right-click on the kotlin for creating the folder.

[image: Crating in the wrong folder]

I want to change the java folder for the whole project.

Comment: TIL, after many years of using Android Studio, there’s a wizard for creating Activities and Fragments. I just right-click the folder and create a new Kotlin class.

Comment: Same for me, right click, new kotlin file or class. All you have to next is extend target class, and later make your layout(s)

Comment: Sounds like an Android Studio bug, I'd report it. You can do so by clicking Help -> Submit feedback.